# Are strings generally considered objects?

Tags: python, string, oop, object, lua

I come from the languages of Lua and Python, both in which treat their string values as objects. I'm just wondering, *are* string values actually considered objects? I mean, in Lua you can configure their metatables and use methods on them, and in Python you can straight up say something like `print("".format)`

Another example (in Lua) could be adding a method to a string value like so:

```
#Prototype object
local proto = {}

function proto:print()
    print(self) -- "self" will be the string
end

#String's metatable
local mt = getmetatable("")
local index = mt.__index

#Direct nil references to the prototype object
setmetatable(index, { __index = proto })

#Create a string
local str = "hello"
str:print() #Call it's method
```

The code above would print the string to the output window once "print" is called, as expected. So are string values objects just like any other data structure in Lua? And does the same go for Python and other languages as well? **Are there any notable differences between string objects and other objects within the language, besides the fact they're different data types?**

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: "and other languages as well" - no. For one thing, not all languages are object-oriented; so "string is an object" does not even make sense for them. Some languages don't even have the concept of a string (C being the notable example). Even in OO languages, it is not necessarily the case: for example, in JavaScript, a string is a primitive, not an object, but it will automatically coerce to `String`, an object wrapper, if you try to use methods on it.

Comment: in general str is a builtin type that cannot have new attributes attatched to it (eg no you cannot add new methods to it) ... however there is stuff like `forbiddenfruit` that allows you to `curse` builtins with new attributes

Comment: @William: Define "object". The term has more meaning that you're giving here. And different languages give the word different meanings.

Comment: The Lua metamethod example you give is interesting. You are actually adding the method to the "class," not the object.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are NOT objects. Quoting Lua manual:

> There are eight basic types in Lua: nil, boolean, number, string,
>   function, userdata, thread, and table. ....
>
> **Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects**:
>   variables do not actually contain these values, only references to
>   them. Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always
>   manipulate references to such values; these operations do not imply
>   any kind of copy.

This sentence

> Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects

means that **ONLY these are objects**, **the rest are basic types (primitives)**.